# how to push array of values in php?

Tags: php

i need help on a php foreach looping on values, pushing to array and converting to json.

The following code displays last values only.
i want to, for example more than two emails above the limit displayed. 
please help me.

```
public executeInvite(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $email = $request->getParameter("email");
    foreach($email as $e)
    {

        if($invitationlimit>0)
        {
            $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->from ('invitationwp')
                ->where('email_address = ?', $em);
                $this->invitedlist = $q->fetchArray();
                $message ="success";
        }
        else
        {
          $emails = array();
          $count = 0;
          $emails[$count++] =$em;
          $message = $emails;
        }
        $invitationlimit--; 
    }
    return $this->renderText(json_encode($message));
}
```

Comment: use function `array_push()`

Comment: Please apply yourself when posting, read what you wrote and don't use SMS style.

Comment: $emails = array(),array_push($emails, $em);
      
$message = $emails;already i tried array_push,this also display above the limit two emails emails means display last one.

Comment: `Doctrine_Query` will never run because `$invitationlimit` is never set.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following. Hopefully it will help you.

```
$emails=array();
$arr=array('abcd@gmail.com','abcde@gmail.com','bcdf@gmail.com');
foreach($arr as $val)
{
    $emails[]=$val;
}
print_r($emails);
print_r(json_encode($emails));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to fix your code but it doesn't make sense to me.

You should not create an array in the else statement, or it will be overwritten everytime.

Maybe that's better:

```
public executeInvite(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $emails = array();
    $email = $request->getParameter("email");
    $count = 0;

    foreach($email as $e) {

        if($invitationlimit>0) {

           $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
           ->from ('invitationwp')
           ->where('email_address = ?', $em);
       $this->invitedlist = $q->fetchArray();
                   $message ="success";
        }
        else
            $emails[$count++] = $em;

        $invitationlimit--; 
    }
    return $this->renderText(json_encode($emails));
}
```

Comment: i tried this way.but still same problem display  last element only.

Comment: are you sure you are doing a loop over the $emails in your html template? Paste the code where you actually do the display.